# how to count records with newest date only

Tags: mysql, sql, date, unique, greatest-n-per-group

How do I modify this MySQL query to only count leadIDs from table leads where column 'Date' contains the newest (youngest) date?

```
SELECT COUNT(leadID) as accepted FROM leads WHERE change like '%OK%'
```

The problem is that leadID can have multiple instances in table leads. The original query result is "4" because of one duplicate. The correct result is "3".

The date is stored in this format: 2011-10-26 18:23:52. The result should take hours and minutes into consideration when determining the youngest date.

TABLE leads:

```
leadID | date                | change
1      | 2011-10-26 18:23:52 | BAD
1      | 2011-10-26 17:00:00 | OK
2      | 2011-10-26 19:23:52 | OK
3      | 2011-10-26 20:23:52 | OK
4      | 2011-10-26 21:23:52 | OK
5      | 2011-10-26 22:23:52 | BAD
```

Comment: please provide the sample data as well.. with desired result .. if possible provide what and all you have tried, if any.

Comment: this condition on change column **like '%OK%'** you want while selecting count also...????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
select count(distinct l1.leadId) as accepted from leads l1
left join leads l2
on l1.leadId = l2.leadId and l1.date < l2.date
where l2.date is null and l1.`change` like '%OK%'
```

Comment: I'm like you i don't understand the -1

Comment: I don't know who voted this -1. Your query result shows "0". Your query without the max part [and date = (select max(date) from leads)] shows 3, which is correct. But we don't know which of the two entries the query counted.

Comment: @user1291842: Are you sure you have 3 records with the exact hour, minute and second? Do those records have to be the `youngest` or `greatest` that have `change like '%OK%'` or do they have to be the `greatest` of the whole table?

Comment: all dates have hr/min/sec. see sample data just added to question.

Answer (score 0):

You must decide what you mean by newest date: the single latest? yesterday? today?

if yesterday, then add this to your query clause

```
  select * from mytable where date >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
```

Comment: "newest date" means the youngest date in a group of dates. it does not necessarily mean "today" or "yesterday". the "newest date" could be a date 3 years ago because other dates in the group are 4 and 5 years old.

Comment: Then use Having with max(getdate()) date. Look up HAVING in mysql manual.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using oracle database you can use max() function to extract newest date from the table, further to check with the table for this newest date :-

```
SELECT COUNT(leadID) as accepted FROM leads WHERE change like '%OK%'
and date_col = (select max(date_col) from leads)
```

I am assuming that with newest date your mean is about newest in the table data..

changes :- as per changes in question and as per mentioned in commends .. 
I think you want to take newest date among the records having "change" column value like '%OK%' and want to count distinct leadId

please try the following query-

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct leadID) as accepted FROM leads WHERE change like '%OK%'
    and date_col = (select max(date_col) from leads WHERE change like '%OK%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: the original query result is "4" because of one duplicate. The correct result is "3". Your query's result shows "0".

Comment: @user1291842 kindly provide the data for the used three columns .. you can update your question with this..

Comment: as per your example latest date with ok as change column value 2011-10-26 21:23:52 having only one record so that's why my select query was giving only 1 as result of count.

Comment: we need to count all instances of "ok". in case there are duplicate IDs, we only look at the ID with the youngest date. if the status is "ok" we count the ID, else we don't.

Comment: @user1291842 kindly explain in the example how you are getting 3 as count. see as I asked in previous comment also newest date is 2011-10-26 21:23:52 (with time HHMISS now If we have to count based on the youngest date the count will come only 1 with OK as change column value..

Answer (score -1):

You can try (in case your date is a int like return by time() function)

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(leadID) as accepted FROM leads WHERE change like '%OK%' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1"
```

You will only extract the newest entry.

Edit: This shouldalso works for your date format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

Edit 2: Okay, I did not understood your question.
You have a table lead: leadid date
You want to count the number of row for the newset date.

Like another pointed out you can use the MAX operator:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct leadid)
FROM LEAD AS l,
( SELECT MAX(Date) mdate FROM Lead ) AS MaxDate
WHERE l.date = MaxDate.mdate
AND l.change like '%OK%'
```